# How to Loop JSON Data & Parse without Array in JSON file

Tags: java, android, arrays, json, loops

I'm trying to parse JSON data that has no array, at the moment my code loops through a JSONArray and works fine.

### ISSUE/ERROR

I'm not sure how to do the same with an JSON without an array. how do I loop when I don't have an array length to deal with in a JSON with no array.

### Code: - Currently works for JSON data with array

```
JSONArray inbox = null;

List<NameValuePair> params = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();

 // getting JSON string from URL
  JSONObject json = jsonParser.makeHttpRequest(INBOX_URL, "GET",
                params);

try {

        inbox = json.getJSONArray(TAG_ARRAY);
    inbox.toString();

 // looping through All messages
 for (int i = 0; i < inbox.length(); i++) {
 JSONObject c = inbox.getJSONObject(i);

    // Storing each json item in variable
String id = c.getString(TAG_ID);
String person = c.getString(TAG_PERSON);
….. 
…..
…..
// creating new HashMap
                HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();

                // adding each child node to HashMap key => value
                map.put(TAG_ID, id);
                map.put(TAG_FROM, person);
….. 
…..
…..
```

### JSON WITHOUT ARRAY

```
[
    {
        "id": "1",
        "person": "David",
        "thur": "",
        "grade": "15",
        "round": "",
        "tour": ""
    },
    {
        "id": "T2",
        "person": "Mary",
        "thur": "",
        "grade": "13",
        "round": "",
        "tour": ""
    },


]
```

### JSON WITH ARRAY - Code above works fine for this

```
{
    "id": [
        {
            "id": "1",
            "person": "Jason",
            "thur": "F",
            "grade": "17",
            "round": "2"
        },
        {
            "id": "2",
            "person": "Joe",
            "grade": "F",
            "score": "16",
           "round": "3"
        }

]
```

Comment: you need to change `makeHttpRequest` so it can return a JSONArray.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried this?

> `JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject();
>           try {
>               JSONArray jsonArray = new JSONArray(jsonObject.toString());
>           } catch (JSONException e) {
>               e.printStackTrace();
>           }`

But I advice you to use Google Library GSON (https://github.com/google/gson) to get JSON values from rest client

Answer (score 0):

dont know how your parser method (makeHttpRequest()) works
but change the defination of the makeHttpRequest() method ..so it return jsonarray..
as your json is of jsonarray..which further contains jsonobject at each index

```
JSONArray inbox = null;
List<NameValuePair> params = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();

// getting JSON string from URL
JSONArray json = jsonParser.makeHttpRequest(INBOX_URL, "GET",params);

try {
    //inbox = json.getJSONArray(TAG_ARRAY);
    //inbox.toString();

    //comment the above 2 line and the rest is same
    // looping through All messages
    for (int i = 0; i < json.length(); i++) {
    JSONObject c = json.getJSONObject(i);

    // Storing each json item in variable
    String id = c.getString(TAG_ID);
    String person = c.getString(TAG_PERSON);
    // creating new HashMap
    HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();

    // adding each child node to HashMap key => value
    map.put(TAG_ID, id);
    map.put(TAG_FROM, person);
```